# javascript blob.slice()でカットしたオーディオデータが思い通りの動きにならない。

Tags: javascript, audio

javascriptを使い30秒だけ切り取ったオーディオデータを投稿するポートフォリオアプリを作っています。
FFmpeg.jsライブラリを使いwavデータに変換させてinputのrangeでスタート地点をきめてそこから30秒切り取る動作にしたいのですが、 [blob.slice()](https://lab.syncer.jp/Web/API_Interface/Reference/IDL/Blob/slice/) の第一引数が0のときは0秒から30秒切り取られたものがaudioタグのsrcに反映されて再生します。

しかし0以外にするとaudioタグが再生できなくなってしまいます。
自力で解決できなく困ってます。どうかご助力の方お待ちしてます。

HTML

```
<input class="upload_hidden offset-9" type="file" id="sound" accept="audio/*" name="sound">
<div id="currentTime"></div>
<div id="audition"></div>
<div id="resize"></div>
```

javascript

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.9.4/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>

<script>
const sound = document.getElementById('sound');
const title = document.getElementById('title');
const resize = document.getElementById('resize');
const audition = document.getElementById('audition');
const currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');


const {
            createFFmpeg,
            fetchFile
        } = FFmpeg;
        const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
            log: true
        });
        const transcode = async ({
            target: {
                files
            }
        }) => {
            await ffmpeg.load();
            ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'music', await fetchFile(files[0]));
            await ffmpeg.run('-i', 'music', '-vn', '-ac', '2', '-ar', '44100', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-f', 'wav', 'output.wav');

            const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.wav');

            dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], {
                type: 'audio/wav'
            }));
            audition.innerHTML = '<audio src="' + dataUrl + '"controls id="sample"></audio>';

            const fileTitle = (() => {
                const files = sound.files;
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

                reader.onload = () => {
                    currentTime.innerHTML = '<input type="range" value="0" id="sampleCurrentTime" min="0"   step="1"  onchange="setCurrentTime(this.value)">';
                    const elementReference = document.getElementById('sample');
                    const sampleCurrentTime = document.getElementById('sampleCurrentTime');

                    const timer = setInterval(() => {
                        if (elementReference.readyState > 0) {
                            sampleCurrentTime.max = elementReference.duration; //デフォルトでrangeの総再生時間が反映されないのでそれを処理
                            clearInterval(timer);
                        }
                    }, 300);


                    console.log(elementReference.duration);
                    resize.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id=change>30秒ピックアップ<button>'
                    const change = document.getElementById('change');
                    change.addEventListener('click', async () => {
                        let postForm = null;
                        const byte = {
                            'start': parseInt(elementReference.currentTime * 0.172 * 1024 * 1024),
                            'end': parseInt((elementReference.currentTime + 30) * 0.172 * 1024 * 1024)
                        };

                        const sliceData = new Blob([data.buffer], {
                            type: "audio/wav"
                        }).slice(byte.start, byte.end, 'audio/wav');

                        const reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(sliceData);
                        reader.onload = () => {
                           let dataURI = reader.result;
                           console.log(dataURI);
                           audition.innerHTML = '<audio src="' + dataURI + '"controls id="sample"></audio>';
                        }
                    });
                };
              })
            fileTitle();
        }

  const setCurrentTime = (currentTime) => {
            const elementReference = document.getElementById('sample');

            elementReference.currentTime = currentTime;
        }

        sound.addEventListener('change', transcode);
</script>
```

Comment: wavファイルは生のpcmではないので、先頭にはヘッダーがあります。波形を弄りたい場合はs16leなど生pcmにしてください。ただ長さを変えたい場合は、ffpmpegの-ssと-iの方が適してると思います。.jsで使えるかは知りませんが。

Comment: wavの知識があまり定着していないのとmp3に変換したら思った動きになったので、それで進めていこうと思います。
回答ありがとうございました。